# Quark-Gluon Plasma

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

Is there any perfect evidence for the Quark-Gluon Plasma at LHC or RHIC at Brookhaven?

Link to any paper will be really appreciated.

Comment: Define "perfect evidence."

Comment: For the LHC, I know that proton-lead ion collisions are used to study the quark-gluon plasma state, albeit the system is too small to be considered as a real quark-gluon plasma. The system can still be used to study certain features of this state. I believe the same holds true for lead-lead interactions, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? There is no such thing as "perfect evidence" in high energy physics, there is only statistical inference. For papers you can search e.g. https://cms-results.web.cern.ch/cms-results/public-results/publications/Run2/index.html for publications starting with "HIN" (Heavy Ion).

Comment: if you go to the cern document server and search for quark gluon plasma http://cds.cern.ch/  you will get a number of hits

Comment: Like the one, we have for quarks, Higgs etc..

Comment: There's some relevant info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(particle_physics)

Answer (score 1):

Some theorists have thought that the predicted quark-gluon plasma has been produced, but experimental groups are more cautious,

- *“However, detailed analyses of the data also make it clear that this hot, dense medium has properties that are surprising, and not yet fully understood in terms of the early expectations for the quark gluon plasma.”* Relativistic Heavy Ion Collider, Brookhaven National Laboratory, 2005, [Hunting the Quark Gluon Plasma](https://www.bnl.gov/npp/docs/Hunting%20the%20QGP.pdf), results from the first three years. Formal Report, BNL -73847-2005

It appears that the new form of matter behaves more like a liquid than a plasma, as though composed of constituent particles which tend to flow together rather than randomly,
as predicted by asymptotic freedom. In the absence of viable calculations showing
exactly how quark soup should behave, it is difficult to assess implications.

Comment: It's true that "quark-gluon plasma" is a bit of a misnomer, since QGP is strongly coupled for most of its evolution. But the strongly-coupled liquid-like ensemble of quarks and gluons no longer bound into hadrons is nevertheless still called quark-gluon plasma by those in the field, mostly out of historical inertia, even though everyone is aware that it's not a weakly-coupled soup like people originally believed. Don't judge the evidence by the name alone.

Comment: @probably_someone, those working in the field may know, but that is not everyone. In particular it is not everyone reading a forum. In any case, the point is not what it is called, but the goodness of fit between theory and observation.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that quark gluon plasma did exist at the center of the LHC. They probably did not physically see it of course. They did indirectly prove for it(detectors might have proved it too). According to theory protons(neutrons would also melt into quarks and gluons but protons are colided in the LHC) would melt. The detectors might have still seen the quarks and felt it. The charges of the quarks could be felt.

https://home.cern/science/physics/heavy-ions-and-quark-gluon-plasma